# Which keymap variable contains the bindings for `M-x`?

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, escape

The Help for key `M-x` key says

```
M-x runs the command execute-extended-command (found in global-map),
which is an interactive compiled Lisp function.

It is bound to <execute>, <menu>, M-x.
```

But in the `global-map` there is no entry for `M-x`, there are only entries for `execute` and `menu`. Where is the `M-x` binding present ?

Answer (score 1):

You say: *"But in the global-map there is no entry for `M-x`, there are only entries for execute and menu."*

That's not true. If you are just using `C-h v global-map` then it's difficult to tell, unless you're good at reading the Lisp representation of a keymap.

Instead, load library [`help-fns+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/help-fns%2b.el) ([Help+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HelpPlus)) and use `C-h M-k global-map`, to see a human-readable key listing for that keymap. There you'll see this entry, for `M-x`:

```
M-x   execute-extended-command
```

`C-h M-k` is bound to command `describe-keymap`.

[Emacs 27 will also have such a command, based on the one in `help-fns+.el`, but the one in `help-fns+.el` is still a bit better, IMO. Some of the features of the `help-fns+.el` definition weren't adopted for vanilla Emacs.]

---

There is, however, another keymap variable that contains the `execute-extended-command` binding for `M-x`: variable **`esc-map`**.

Meta keys are in fact on that keymap.  `ESC` followed by a key sequence is essentially the same as `META` followed by that same key sequence. So `M-x` is equivalent to `ESC x`. `ESC` is not a *modifier* key here; it's a prefix key.

When you see keys listed in `*Help*` you'll often notice `ESC` listed as a prefix key, and you'll see `ESC` followed by some key sequence listed as a binding.

And you'll see in the value shown for `C-h v global-map` an entry for `ESC-prefix`, which means that ESC is a prefix key globally.

Comment: I executed "M-x load-library" "help-fns" and then as soon as i press "C-h M-k" , the command mini buffer prints "C-h M-k is undefined". I use emacs 26.3 and "describe-keymap" command is not found.  I launched emacs with no config(emacs -q)

Comment: Did you follow the links for [`help-fns+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/help-fns%2b.el)? Note the **`+`**.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480173/show-keys-in-emacs-keymap-value